# Fill empty cells with values from a list in another column

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreasheet:

```
     A                                 B                C
1    =IF(B1<>"",B1;OFFSET(B1,-1,0))   CompanyA
2    =IF(B2<>"",B2;OFFSET(B2,-1,0))                
3          
4                                     CompanyB
5                                     CompanyC
6
7                                     CompanyD
```

In column B I have a list of different companies and it might happen that they are empty rows *(in this case row2, row3 or row6)* between the companies.
In column A I want to achieve that the empty rows are filled with the company names so in the end the spreadsheet looks like this:

```
     A                         B                C
1    Company A              CompanyA
2    Company A               
3    Company A      
4    Company B              CompanyB
5    Company C              CompanyC
6    Company C
7    Company D              CompanyD
```

I tried to use the If-formula with the offset in column A but it only works when there is not more than one empty row so it only works for CompanyB,C and D but not for company A.

Do you have any idea which formula I have to use in column A to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls refer the snap below

In A2 apply the below formula and drag down

```
=IF(B2<>"",B2,A1)
```

[image]

**EDIT #1: Another method if data starts with row 1**

if the data starts with B1 then apply the below formula in A1 and drag down

```
=IF(B1<>"",B1,IF(ROW()=1,B1,OFFSET(A1,-1,0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Provided the first cell, say B2,  is not empty try with:`=B2` in cell A2 and `=IF(B3<>"";B3;A2)`in cell A3 and fill down.